# How to delete .htaccess via terminal (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, dedicated

I have a dedicated server and i cant delete, rename or move .htaccess file on my ftp.

How i can delete on terminal? my server is ubuntu and i have root access

The permission are set 644

I fixed using chattr -a .htaccess then i was able to delete, but i dont have idea what happen

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 .htaccess` then `sudo rm .htaccess`

Comment: i get changing permissions of .htaccess : operation not permitted

Answer (score 2):

You can type the following command:

```
rm -rf file-name
```

on your terminal

Comment: fixed using chattr -a

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a couple of steps. When server does not allow to erase **.htaccess** file on account folder, I logged in as root. So steps:
Use commands

> ```
> chattr -i .htaccess
> chmod 777 .htaccess
> ```

Then you can delete that **.htaccess** file, the attributes of .htaccess has been changed so not even a root user can even modify, change attributes at all. The command **chattr**  makes a file untouchable even if you are sudo root, owner, etc